# How to split a environment variable sentence in two items (VAR,VALUE)?

Tags: python

I have a script python that get the environment variables string and split in variable and value.

It is very easy to split with python:

```
export_str = 'VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE2'
for var_value in export_str.split(' '):
   var,value=var_value.split('=')
   print var, value
```

But the problem is that the variables can be more complex.

```
export_str = ''' VAR1="VALUE1 OTHER VALUE" VAR2=VALUE2 VAR3=VALUE_3 VAR4="${VALUE5}=VALUE6"'''
```

In this case the python script is wrong.

Is there a better way to split this variables?

Edited

Or more complex cases like as:

```
export_str = '''VAR5="VALUE'5" VAR6='VALUE"6' VAR7='VALUE7' '''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split using `re`.

```
import re
export_str = 'VAR1="VALUE1 OTHER VALUE" VAR2=VALUE2 VAR3=VALUE_3 VAR4="${VALUE5}=VALUE6"'
re.split(r'\s(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)',export_str)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE6jQ1/7

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is very good. (Just add a scape char in \")

Comment: What about next case: `export_str = 'VAR1=\'VALUE"1\' VAR2="VALUE\' VALUE2"` to split `VAR1='VALUE"1'` and `VAR2="VALUE' VALUE2"` ?

Comment: @moylop260 you should ask a new question for that case and along with other cases as well